# Calling a non-static method on a JPanel within a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame that creates a JPanel class inside itself. Inside the JPanel class, I have a function that draws a rectangle and then repaints the area, but I have no way to get to the JPanel and run the method from the main method.

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() { //This is run by the main method
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Program Name");
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel()); //I need to access this MyPanel that I just created.
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

    Utils.debug("Swing JFrame initialized."); // don't worry about this
    Utils.print("Initialization complete!"); //or this

    Utils.sleep(1.0); //or this

    //This is where I need to access the MyPanel class inside JFrame f.
}
```

Comment: I _always_ worry about invoking `sleep()` on the event dispatch thread.

Comment: The program's flow basically stops at that point, so it's not a problem. I'm planning on designing the program to look a bit like a KhanAcademy javascript program, all this is just setting up my "canvas."

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution immediately after posting this.

```
MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
f.add(panel);

...

panel.method(args);
```

I'm going to leave this here so that if anyone else has this problem, they can see.